# What is the difference between snapshot dependency and finished build trigger in TeamCity?

Tags: build, triggers, dependencies, teamcity, snapshot

It appears to me that the function of snapshot dependency completely supersedes that of finished build trigger in TeamCity. Can anyone explain more the effect of these methods if they result in different chain behaviour? As an example, if I had a build chain of A->B

Does the chain actually behave any differently between these three setups?

- Setup 1: Single finished build trigger of A in B.
- Setup 2: Single snapshot dependency of A in B.
- Setup 3: Both finished build trigger of A AND snapshot dependency of A defined in B.

I understand that one can kind of treat Snapshot Dependency as "AND" operation of all the dependees, while Finished Build Trigger works like "OR" operation amongst the dependees. But in the context of a sequential chain, is there any difference?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 20):

A "Snapshot Dependency" and "Finished Build" trigger are very different. one is basically a "push" operation while the other is a "pull" operation, respectively.

**Setup 1:**
If I have build configs **A** and **B** where **B** has a "Finished Build" trigger on **A**, then the opposite behavior is true. Triggering **B** will have no affect on **A**, but triggering **A** will effectively trigger **B** once it has finished.

**Setup 2:**
If I have the exact same setup but instead **B** has a snapshot dependency on **A**, then whenever **B** is triggered, **A** will run first, or at least check to see if it needs to run, before running **B**. IF only **A** is triggered, then **B** will not be triggered.

**Setup 3:**
Setup 3 is slightly different because it doesn't JUST depend on the "Finished Build" trigger or the snapshot dependency. it ALSO depends on the initial trigger (VCS, scheduled, or whatever). for example, if you have a VCS trigger on **A**, and **B** has both the "Finished Build" trigger and "snapshot dependency" on **A**, then you effectively get the behavior of Setup 1. **A** will get triggered on VCS changes and **B** will be triggered AFTER **A** (using the same snapshot). In fact, without the snapshot setup, it is not guaranteed that **B** will use the same snapshot as **A**, which may or may not be what you want.

So in general, when you want a "left-to-right" trigger process, you use BOTH finished build triggers and snapshot dependencies to guarantee the sanctity of the build collateral.

If, on the other hand, you have your initial trigger (VCS or scheduled or whatever) setup on **B**, then having the "finished build" trigger is somewhat nullified, because **B** will always be triggered first (but not run), and then it will trigger all of its dependencies and automatically run after they finish.

hope that helps. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As you said, there's a big difference if a config snapshot-depends on *multiple* other configs (Z snapshot-depending on both X and Y). But you're not interested in that...

It's true to say that in the trivial A->B scenario Setups 1 .. 3 are close to equivalent. Of course, only if the events that trigger A and B are one-to-one (e.g. both A and B are triggered on the same VCS root; or they use different VCS roots but are only triggered manually). If this is true, then your A->B chain is super-trivial and might be possible to implement within a single build configuration.

Other subtle differences that come to mind:

1. Passing parameters down the chain.

   - Suppose A and B share some user-defined parameter "foo". The A->B snapshot dependency lets you define `%foo%` in A and reuse it in B using `%dep.A.foo%`. That's really convenient because you don't need to worry about keeping the value of `%foo%` in sync between A and B.
   - Now suppose that you want to manually trigger the A->B chain with a custom value of `%foo%` (you'll specify the value in the "Run..." dialog).
   - Since TC cannot pass the value *up* the chain (from B to A), you must really trigger A and specify the custom value there. When A finishes, it will trigger B, which will overtake the custom value. That's Setup 3.
   - You can't achieve the same with Setup 2, i.e. by triggering B with the custom value. The custom value would have no way of getting across to A.
2. Scheduling.

   - Suppose you have a scarce resource, and B cannot possibly run for every commit. You end up with each run of B "containing" (covering) multiple VCS commits. At the same time, A has no problems running for every commit.
   - In Setups 1 and 3, if you have a VCS trigger on A, you'll end up with

     - a run of A for every commit
     - a run of B with "aggregated" commits (each run covering multiple changes)
   - In Setup 2, if you have a VCS trigger on B only, you'll end up with aggregated commits in *both* A and B. Which may or may not be what you want...
3. Different VCS roots.

   - If A and B have different VCS roots, then Setup 1 (with VCS trigger on A only) and Setup 2 (with VCS trigger on B only) will behave quite differently.

In general, I agree the "pull" nature of snapshot dependencies (Setup 2) is much more appealing. Combine with the trigger if needed (Setup 3).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.
In my situation, sharing parameters and scarce resource are very rare, so I will likely default to only snapshot dependency (setup 2), and use the combo (setup 3) if there's specific behaviour required with different VCS roots.

Comment: Could you clarify in setup 3, does A get run twice if the snapshop dependency has the option "Do not run new build if there is a suitable one" **UNCHECKED**? as in... something triggers A, when A completes, _Finished Build_ kicks in and tries to put B on queue, THEN _Snapshot Dependency_ kicks in and puts A on queue again before B is queued. It does NOT place another A on the queue when I tested this setup but I thought in theory, it should. Does TeamCity have internal logic to ignore the snapshot dependency's queuing step if finished build trigger exist?

Comment: Even with this option unchecked, I don't think A should be re-queued. That would be terribly impractical and I can't think of anyone who may desire that behaviour. (I guess you don't want that behaviour either, you're just wondering what this option does if not *that*.) What this option does, I believe, is this: kick A, let B trigger. Both have run once. Now manually trigger only B, with no code changes since the last B build. Should that trigger A again or not? That's where this option comes to play.

Comment: yea i'm just trying to understand the option. I do not want that behaviour, so i know i can safely use setup 3 and not cause re-queue either way - even though teamcity's own description isn't clear about that part. thanks for your help. sorry i can't upvote answer.