# TeamCity artifact dependecy from private builds

Tags: teamcity

Is there any way to set build dependencies on artifacts, which was generated in **private builds** on another project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have B, which depends on A (A-->B), and A generates artifacts that B needs to consume.

Yes, this should work with private builds. You may have to set up a snapshot dependency (A-->B). A finish-build trigger is insufficient, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33252745/1540600). Thus, set up the snapshot dependency and trigger B rather than A; B will trigger A itself.

Comment: In this scenario, B will be personal too?
Is it possible to launch personal build A, depended on B and B will be in trunk?

Comment: I don't think so. Both B and A will get your personal changes applied (in the form of a "patch" applied to the workspace).